# Валидация данных веб-приложения

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net, валидация

Начал изучать ASP.NET и добрался до валидации данных, которую можно проводить как на [стороне клиента](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/19.4.php), так и на [стороне сервера](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/19.3.php). На чьей стороне лучше реализовать проверку правильности данных, которые ввёл пользователь, или нужно проверять на обеих сторонах одновременно? Есть ли разграничения, какие данные следует проверять на стороне клиента, а какие на стороне сервера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Лучше всего проводить валидацию на двух сторонах.**

На стороне клиента надо проводить валидацию, чтоб пользователь лишний раз не дергал бекенд, с неправильными данными.

Если вдруг, пользователю удалось отправить данные на бекенд, то там тоже есть валидация, которая не пропустит эти данные.

Например, пользователь может отправить запрос через какой-нибудь `REST` клиент, и если на сервере не будет валидации данных, то произойдет ошибка.